# DEBUG notices in system.log

Tags: error, debug, log

Unsure what triggers these in the system.log but it's writing hundreds of these to the log constantly.

```
DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?><widgets></widgets>

DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?><jstranslator></jstranslator>

DEBUG (7): <config/>
```

For example.

Please could someone advise how to debug these or find the cause/how to remove them? Have been unable to find much documentation of these errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That would appear to be custom logging calls which someone didn't strip from their code before deploying it. These are not Magento errors.

What you'll want to look for is calls to Mage::log() in custom code and/or calls which have been added into core files. To check core files, run a diff between your code and a clean code base of the same version. My guess is the chances of them being in core code is high considering they appear to be from someone trying to learn about config XML documents.

Comment: Ahaa, makes sense. Thanks - will hunt them down! :)